# Handle JSON server response in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp

I've seen many similar issues, but they didn't provide answer for my question.
My Server form JSON string and put it into response:

```
List<String> list = getSomeList();
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
System.out.println(jsArray);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(jsArray.toString());
```

But in my javascript handle function when I alert response, it alert ALL page!

```
function handleResponse(){    
 if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){  
  var response = http.responseText;
   if(response){ 
     alert(response); //alert all page!
     var list = JSON.parse(response.toJSON()); //doesn't work! 
 }       
}
```

**Question**: how could I separate only jsArray in javascript?

**P.S.** As I understand, my JSON.parse(response.toJSON()) doesn't work because response contain the whole page?

Comment: does jsArray.toString() return JSON object?

Comment: in debug:
jsArray - JSONArray
jsArray.toString - "["Harkiv","Kiev","Lviv"]"

Comment: I don't know java, but try closing your response writer right after writing your jsArray. It's probably something like response.getWriter().close();
Client-side, JSON.parse() should be sufficient. No need to do response.toJSON()

Comment: response.getWriter().close() - Yes, it is what I want. Thank you )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know java.

Server-side, the problem is probably that your response is not closed after writing your JSON Array, allowing other (html) text to be written. Try this:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(jsArray.toString());
response.getWriter().close();
```

Client-side, responseText is a string, and strings don't have a toJSON() function defined.

```
var list = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
```

should suffice.